# Spark clusters communication

Tags: apache-spark

There are many Apache Spark tutorials in the internet. But almost all of them are high-level tutorials (how to work with Spark data abstractions). I'm interesting in some low-level information about Apache Spark. For understanding of Spark I want to read how Spark clusters communicate with each other (used protocols, load balancing algorithms etc.). Where can I read some info about this?

Comment: Read [the source](https://github.com/apache/spark)?

Comment: here's a book from a guy who read the source https://www.gitbook.com/book/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark/details